# Using Post Request return a multiple values in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity i have created a Post Request from that i want to return the Authentication-Token Header and authorization header and some required json data here is my code

```
private IEnumerator BasketId()
{
    string url = "http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/rest/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS-Site/-/baskets/";
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, "Hello"))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        string token = request.GetResponseHeader("Authentication-token");
        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string jsonResut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request.downloadHandler.data);
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasketId>(jsonResut);
            Debug.Log(obj.Uri);
            Debug.Log("Authentication-Token: " + token);            
            yield return obj.Title;
            yield return token;
        }
    }
}
```

so i could i return the values. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Because Coroutine is not immediate (blocking) so you won't be able to return the response directly. What you need to do is to have an event or callback that will be called when your request completed.

Here is how you can achieve it by passing the callback as argument:

```
private IEnumerator GetBasketId(System.Action<string, BasketId> callback)
{
    string url = "http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/rest/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS-Site/-/baskets/";
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, "Hello"))
    {
       yield return request.SendWebRequest();
       if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
       {
          Debug.Log(request.error);
          if (callback != null)
          {
             callback(null, null);
          }
          // callback?.Invoke(null, null); // for short
          }
          else
          {
             if (callback != null)
             {
                string token = request.GetResponseHeader("Authentication-token");
                string jsonResut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request.downloadHandler.data);
                obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasketId>(jsonResut);
                if (callback != null)
                {
                   callback(token, obj);
                }
                // callback?.Invoke(token, obj); // for short
             }
          }
     }
}
```

so when you want to start the request simply call something like:

```
StartCoroutine(GetBasketId((token, basketId) =>
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
   {
      // Handle error
   }
   else
   {
      // Handle success
      Debug.Log("Token: " + token);
      Debug.Log(basketId.Title);
   }
});
```